# reshape matrix from n by 1 to m by n matrix

Tags: matlab

I am trying to reshape the matrix:

```
A  = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22]
```

to this form

```
B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11; 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22]
```

I am trying this: `B = reshape(A,2,11)` but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the order of your elements, you need to use this instead:

```
B = reshape(A,11,2)'
```

It reshapes on the other dimension, then transposes the resulting matrix.

Comment: I always recommend using `transpose` instead of the `'` notation. The standard `'` notation is the hermitian or conjugate transpose. So if you have imaginary numbers, the standard `'` notation will invert the imaginary portion. If you want to use that notation, make it `.'` instead. I can't count how many times this has given me wrong answers on projects/work in school

Comment: Just make sure that you don't make the opposite mistake and break something by (mis)using the scalar transpose when doing actual math operations.